# Summer 19 Right-to-Left LEX

Tags: lightning, lightning-community

We built a Community for our users, and set the default language to Hebrew. After enabling the Beta right-to-left in the User Interface settings, it worked great.

But then along came Summer '19.
According to the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_globalization_rtl.htm) they fixed something to make it work (I don't understand what, that Note is big on buzzwords and short on actual details). But they also broke the Beta thing we were using until now. That option no longer exists in the User Interface setting.

So now, there is no way to set the user interface to right-to-left. And even though the default community language is Hebrew, we're seeing the whole thing being left-to-right.

I found a workaround where I added a custom styling to the theme:

```
.siteforceCptBody{
    direction: rtl;
}
```

But that is not a long term solution, as we all know " future releases of template components might not support all CSS customizations."

Am I just missing something, or do I need to open a case to Salesforce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a case with Salesforce and they got back to me basically saying: it's a beta feature and I guess we broke something? Anyway, this is pretty low on our priority list and we don't have the resources to fix it so just deal.

I did understand that the lack of checkbox in Settings no longer exists because it is automatically enabled for users with a RTL language selected. That's what the release notes said.